# Build MySql Query

Tags: mysql

I have a database table called `private_message`. I run the following query on it to get a result of all the user id's that one user (47762) sent a private message to:

```
SELECT `to_id` FROM `private_message` WHERE `from_id` = 47762
```

I now want to use this query or some other way on another table called `users` to get the email address of all the users who received the email address from 47762.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `sid` = (SELECT `to_id` FROM `private_message` WHERE `from_id` = 47762)
```

In the above query, users.sid is the same as private_messages.to_id

I got the error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

What I want is to get the email addresses of users that were sent a private message from user 47762 but the users table.

I'm a novice with MYSQL so would appreciate some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IN` instead od `=` since you can't compate (`=`) sid to multiple values.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `sid` IN (SELECT `to_id` FROM `private_message` WHERE `from_id` = 47762)
```

Anyway you can do a `JOIN` here instead:

```
SELECT u.* FROM `users` AS u
JOIN `private_message` AS pm ON u.`sid` = pm.`to_id`
WHERE pm.`from_id` = 47762
```

It will be more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Your first select statement did the job perfectly.

Comment: I advice you to use `JOIN` where possible as long as you don't have as real reason to use subquery.

Comment: Both statements worked. But yes, JOIN is more efficient.